# Dynamic Paint texture bake fails

Tags: error, dynamic-paint

I'm fairly new to blender, and there's something I can't manage to solve. I'm making a simulation with dynamic paint, and I want the mask as a texture, so no vertex paint but an image sequence. I set up everything but when I click "bake image sequence" an error shows up saying "dynamic paint: bake failed: canvas mesh not updated". I tried with a very simple scene too, an animated cube on a plane, and it gives me the same error. I made the UVs, set up the brush and all, so I don't understand where the problem is... On google I couldn't find anything.
I'm using 2.8, so could it be a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance!

[image: These are my settings]

Comment: Experienced the same problem yesterday. I +1 your question. By the way, I haven't really dug deep into the code but the error message that we are seeing is not something added in v2.80 (it was there 6 years ago). (In my case, I ended up baking to vertex paint and then painfully baking frame-by-frame to an external texture file)

Comment: On facebook they told me in 2.8 dynamic paint textures are not ready yet... So I think we'll have to either wait or use 2.79

Comment: Use the latest blender..it is working now..